# Access to my Azure web site without ftp

Tags: wordpress, azure, azure-web-app-service

My Wordpress site on Azure has been hacked. I need to get acces to the files, and make som changes without FTP.

Is that possible?

Best regards
- Geir

Comment: @mevius, there is no SSH on Azure Websites!

Comment: Yes, you can. Using Visual Studio Online codename Monaco. Follow the instructions [here to do so](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/monaco/archive/2014/06/26/how-to-access-visual-studio-online-monaco-from-the-new-azure-portal.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Another way to access it is just to use the Kudu extension. Login to the portal and then navigate to the_name_of_your_site.scm.azurewebsites.net e.g. supersite.scm.azurewebsites.net.

From there you can access the console and also browse files, edit them etc. It's less fancy than the VSO Anton proposed, but it's faster and simpler to access.

Answer (score 0):

Go to management portal and use WebMatrix option at the bottom to get a dump or edit it online. This give you access to your website.

Also you need to urgently update all your FTP and other access credentials through the same management portal ASAP to block the unauthorized actions over the same.

If you mean that your Azure account credentials it self were hacked? Then immediately recover the same using forgot password options and update it. Also follow above steps to modify all related accesses.